# Хранение массива в памяти

Tags: javascript

Как хранится массив в памяти? В си это непрерывная область памяти с доступом к любому элементу за константу. Такое ли представление массива в JavaScript?

Comment: Сомневаюсь если типы в массивах можно смешивать.

Comment: Если бы не знал что типы можно смешивать, то думал бы что ситуация аналогичная Си)

Comment: в JS фактически нет массивов. задача сводится к тому, за какое время происходит обращение к произвольному свойству объекта.

Comment: @teran, можно сойтись на том, что все зависит от реализации движка. Например для цифровых ключей в движке может быть оптимизация и их значения будут храниться в памяти как обычный массив, но оптимизации может и не быть :)

Answer (score -2):

Ну вообще в памяти он хранится всегда и каждый элемент имеет свой индекс

```
arr[i]
```

Но если ты хочешь переписать его, но сохранить данные (без сервера, естественно) - используй localStorage перенеся его в строку (временно)

```
localStorage.setItem('stringArr', stringArr);
```

и получить его ты сможешь в любой момент

```
localStorage.getItem(stringArr);
```

и перенести в массив по разделителю, который выбрал в начале

С сервером, конечно же проще, но тогда тебе нужны пост и гет запросы с ним. Но получать js код сложно с другого сайта, из-за корс защиты, но ее можно обойти вот так

```
  function req_scrpt() {
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/injected.js'), 
  function (data) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.innerHTML = data;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("onLoad", " injected_main();");
  }
);
}

function file_get_contents(url) {
  console.log(url);
  var req = null;
  try {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e) {}
  if (req == null) throw new Error('XMLHttpRequest not supported');
  req.open("GET", url, false);
  req.send(null);
  return req.responseText;
 }
}
```

Так что сам выбирай что тебе удобнее и что из этого нужно 
(т.к. не совсем понял вопрос - ответил сразу на все, которые на мой взгляд связаны с ним)

Comment: вопрос был про время доступа к элементу, при чем тут `localStorage` ?

Comment: Вопрос вообще не об этом

Comment: Да, я почему-то подумал вопрос про работу с памятью массива и извлечение из нее онного, так что да, моя ошибка

Answer (score -4):

В `JavaScript` массивы представляют собой типы объектов, со специальными конструкторами и методами доступа и выделяют непрерывный блок памяти фиксированной длины:

```
var array = new Array(100);
```

Данный массив не выделит никакой памяти, он просто установит значение свойства `length`. 
Когда вы создаете массив, вам не нужно объявлять размер по мере его роста.
Массивы в `JavaScript` разрежены - это означает, что не все элементы в массиве могут содержать данные, существуют только те элементы, которые содержат фактические данные - это уменьшает объем памяти, используемой массивом.

Если создать пустой массив:

```
var array = [];
```

И заполнить его от 0 до 99 таким образом:

```
array[0] = 0;
array[99] = 100;
```

Длина будет равна 100, но количество элементов в массиве будет равно 2.

Если вы хотите использовать `JavaScript-Arrays` как непрерывные блоки памяти, вы должны изучить [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) - это позволит выделять блок памяти в виде байтового массива и более эффективно обращаться к исходным двоичным данным.